# Why am I getting this Unhandled exception?

Tags: java, throw

Using an interface to handle constants, I can not call a predefined method that throws exception.

```
  public interface ParametresConstantes {
    public static final String DB_CONNEXION = ChargementProjetProperties.getInstance().getValueByKey("conn");
//a red line under the right part of this instruction.
    public static final int SIZE_TEXT_FIELD = 20;
}



public String getValueByKey (String key) throws Exception
{
    String value = null;
    load();
    if (props.containsKey(key))
    {
        value = props.getProperty(key);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception ("no key found");
    }
    return value;
}
```

How to fix it?

**EDIT**

As discussed below, because static block can not work on interface but on the class implementing it, and because the variable is final and cannot be assigned, I temporary replaced in `else` block by `value=""` and removed throw and kept the rest.

Thank you

Comment: please provide the exact error and stack trace.   Also consider that your interface is calling a method that can throw an exception but is not handling it in any way in the interface

Comment: You can't catch exceptions in initializers. Move that code to a method or a static block.

Comment: Or better, don't throw a checked exception, and certainly not the base Exception, from that method. Throw an unchecked IllegalArgumentException instead.

Comment: It is normal because since your method throws an exception, it needs to be surrounded by a try/ catch block when you call it.

Comment: @achref that is a good idea but how do you suggest handling when there is no key?

Comment: you can specify a default behavior in the case that the key don't exist. It can be printing an error message in the catch block, something like 'wrong key, or 'unable to connect'

Comment: @m0skit0 static block is not working, it says ` interface cannot define an initializer`

Comment: @TiyebBellal I didn't notice it was an interface due to poor formatting. You can add the static block in the class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the problem comes from the fact that you cannot use a method which throws an exception here.

Syntactically, it would work with a static initialization block :

```
public static URI uri;

static {
  try {
    uri = new URI("http://www.example.com/image.jpg");
  } catch(Exception e) {
    //Eventually throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

But I strongly advice to not do that. IMHO, static initialization blocks are a clue that there is something wrong with the design.

I think that defining a method is cleaner :

```
public String getDBConnection () {
  return ChargementProjetProperties.getInstance().getValueByKey("conn");
}
```

Comment: *"Static initialization blocks are a clue that there is something wrong with the design"* Interesting, can you please provide any reference?

Comment: I have tried this, but `The interface ParametresConstantes cannot define an initializer` error

Comment: @m0skit0 I admit that It is primarily opinion based. I don't like the idea of potential side-effects at class initialization. + it makes things harder for unit testing. In this use case, dependency injection is probably the best option. Edited the answer in order to precise that it is only an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The `getValueByKey` method throws an exception and you are not catching it anywhere. That is why it is saying that there is an unhandled exception. You should declare the `DB_CONNEXION` in your interface but define it somewhere downstream (classes who have implemented that interface) where you can handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `static final String DB_CONNEXION` initialisation equivalent a static constructor function and in it if a exception be thrown or raised then there has no chance to handle the exception. The better way is to keep your static constructor function exception-free or register a [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)